# get_by method in Ecto

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm using blow.

- Elixir v1.5
- Phoenix v1.3.0

I would like to get db result using like "get_by" method for condition of column not primary key.

```
alias MyApp.MySchema.User

def index(conn, %{"user_name" => user_name}) do
  user = User.get_by!(User, user_name: user_name)
  render(conn, "index.html", user: user)
end
```

I know it does not work. Just I would like to know how to get result by using another columns value for SQL condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. Thanks.

```
User = MyApp.Repo.get_by!(User, user_name: user_name)
```